# QT: Connect a signal with a fundamental type in its signature to a slot with QVariant in its signature

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, variant, qtwidgets

I'd like to connect a signal with one parameter of a fundamental type like

```
void toggled(bool checked)
void valueChanged(int i)
...
```

to a slot with its parameter being of type QVariant:

```
void setValue( QVariant &value )
```

Is that possible using Qt 5.14 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can as long as you change

```
void setValue(QVariant & value)
```

into

```
void setValue(QVariant value)
```

or

```
void setValue(const QVariant & value)
```

otherwise compilation will fail with a static assertion failed (Signal and slot arguments are not compatible).

Answer (score 3):

[Yes, you can connect signals to slots as long as there is an implicit conversion from the signal parameter to the slot parameter](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Given that Qvariant has constructors from int and bool, these constructors will be used to perform the implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks, that theoretically answers the question.